# Regex to match words beginning with A and last words in line

Tags: regex, dictionary

I'd like to apply regular expression to a dictionary text format, like this:

```
[aidwulf] s zool vrsta hijene (Proteles cristata) Aron's beard

[earanzrod] s bot *ivizma (Ver- bascum Thapsus) Abacca

[a'baid'on] vi biti na pomoći, stajati uz *ok abide with
```

I need two regular expressions.First I need a regular expression to match every letter Aa in words before the last in line which begin with letter Aa. In my examples that would match **A** in **Aaron's** in the first example and **a** in **abide** in the third example.

The second regular expression would match every last word in line, (including hyphenated two-words compounds) and words that begin with asterisk. In my examples this expression would match words **beard**, **Abacca**, **with**, as last words in lines, and ***ok**, ***ivizma** as words beginning with an asterisk.

Comment: Which regex engine are you using? This is vital information (see the regex FAQ), especially since you're dealing with more than just ASCII letters.

Comment: ...and what have you tried that didn't work? What programming language are you using?

Comment: Regex Buddy Tim. I haven't tried anything, I only know how to use  Regex Buddy or Expresso , that's all I know Burhan.

Comment: i really didn't understand your problem..

Comment: I apologize Tim, that's wrong formatting, I tried to put that in text, I'll edit now to remove those asterisks. That would be fine, or if possible as the second to last sequence of non-blank characters that do not contain punctuation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First regex:

```
\bA(?=\S*[ \t]+\S+$)
```

(turn on the "Case insensitive" and "^$ match at line breaks" options)

Second regex:

```
\S+$|(?<=^|[ \t])\*\S+
```

(turn on the "^$ match at line breaks" option)

Answer (score 0):

First Regex:

I guess you want words that begin with `a` and which are **before** the last word.

If am right this is what you are looking for

```
\b[aA]\w+\s+[^\s]+$
```

OR

```
\b[aA](?=\w+\s+[^\s]+$)
```

OR

```
(?<=\s)[aA](?=\w+\s+[^\s]+$)
```

OR

```
(?<=^|\s)[aA](?=\w+\s+[^\s]+$)
```

---

Second Regex:

```
 [^\s]+$
```

Comment: The first one matched "abide with", the other three match only "a" in "abide". Thank you for the help Anirudh, Tim's expression worked perfectly.